# Guice Hibernate cannot find entity classes

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, guice

I am setting up a app with Guice and Hibernate 5, i can start my application and i can see that hibernate start. but when i try to query data with hibernate Session i get the error

> org.hibernate.UnknownEntityTypeException: Unable to locate persister: xyz.entity

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence
  xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
  version="2.1">
  <persistence-unit name="db-manager" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <properties>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

My user entity

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
@Table(name = "user")
@Entity(name = "User")
public class User implements Serializable {;

  @Id
  @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
  private String id;

  @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
  private String login;
...
}
```

Dao

```
@Singleton
public class UserDao  {

  private final Provider<EntityManager> em;

  @Inject
  UserDao(Provider<EntityManager> em) {
    this.em = em;
  }

  public User get(String id) {
    Session session = em.get().unwrap(Session.class);

    System.out.println(session);
    User u = session.get(User.class, id);
   return u;
  }

}
```

my test case

```
public class UserDaoTest {

  private static UserDao userDao;

  @BeforeClass
  public static void setup() {
    Map<String, Object> dbProperties = Maps.newHashMap();
    dbProperties.put(AvailableSettings.JPA_PERSISTENCE_PROVIDER, "org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider");
    dbProperties.put(AvailableSettings.SCANNER_DISCOVERY, "class");
    dbProperties.put(AvailableSettings.DRIVER, "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
    dbProperties.put(AvailableSettings.URL, "jdbc:mysql://....");
    dbProperties.put(AvailableSettings.USER, "");
    dbProperties.put(AvailableSettings.PASS, "");
    dbProperties.put(AvailableSettings.DIALECT, "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
    dbProperties.put(AvailableSettings.SHOW_SQL, "true");
    dbProperties.put(AvailableSettings.HBM2DDL_AUTO, "validate");

    dbProperties.put(AvailableSettings.CONNECTION_PROVIDER, "org.hibernate.hikaricp.internal.HikariCPConnectionProvider");
    dbProperties.put("hibernate.hikari.minimumIdle", "5");
    dbProperties.put("hibernate.hikari.maximumPoolSize", "10");
    dbProperties.put("hibernate.hikari.idleTimeout", "30000");



    JpaPersistModule jpaPersistModule = new JpaPersistModule("db-manager").properties(dbProperties);


    Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(jpaPersistModule, // other module -> bind(UserDao.class).asEagerSingleton());

    PersistService persistService = injector.getInstance(PersistService.class);
    persistService.start();

    userDao = injector.getInstance(UserDao.class);

  }

  @Test
  public void test() {
    userDao.get("UXXXXXXX1");
  }
```

And dont know what i am missing, i though entity will be automatically scan, and no need for *xyz..User* in persistence.xml

Comment: Hmmm .... `@Entity(name = "User") ` name seems very rarely used, try only `@Entity`

Comment: I tried and same issue